# htaccess display only web address no directories

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a website `foo.com` a user logs in and is redirected to `foo.com/boo/foo.php`. Is it possible to only display `foo.com` regardless of what directory a user is accessing?  Not sure if they question is clear... Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Enable mod_rewrite and .htaccess through `httpd.conf` and then put this code in your `.htaccess` under `DOCUMENT_ROOT` directory:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)foo\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ boo/foo.php [L]
```

Comment: thank you very much.  I decided to simply do [code]<?php include 'boo/foo.php';?>[/code] in root directory index.php